# swagger microservice integration for body schema

Tags: swagger, microservices, change-management

we have schemas in our swaggers: like this:

[image: swagger schema map into another microservice]

if we have many microservices and use them in many other API routes in another service.

when s.th change  we need to change all schemas in all of our repositories

**EXAMPLE:**

I have this microservice:

```
survey.com/api/docs
```

and I want to use json sample shema in many other microservice like this:

```
app1.com/api/docs
```

and

```
app2.com/api/docs
```

and

```
app3.com/api/docs
```

when we add a property to my main microservice and schema changed I should refactor all my other schemas in other git repositories.

is there any way to map one route to another swagger document to read these schemas from there?

is there any way to manage these changes? by versioning?

> if app1 and app2 and app3 use one route with schema and source API route schema of survey.com changed we should modify all our swagger documentation